# Spring Kafka Batch message reader and writer

Tags: spring-batch, spring-kafka

Correct if my understanding is wrong.

Kafka spring batch is important when we are consuming records through topics and writing to file system or Database.The write process occurs on **batch** mode on file system or database end and not on Kafka end.Thats why  spring kafka batch support came in picture.

It is same in case of reading data in batch from file and writing to kafka topics.Here also the batch process is on file end.

So if we  neither consuming the data from any file nor we are writing to any file in between consumer and producer process so its same like like using normal kafka message listener and message writer?

I read polling factor decides the data consumption in batch in Kafka .Even if we enable batch listener mode then in that case its related to acknowledgement of multiple messages at once.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve without referring to any technology or tool? Also, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: I am trying to consume messages from topic and then i am sending it to another microservice which is generating response for each message. Messages are sent back to producer

Comment: I was intially confused whether spring batch approach would be more  effective here rather than enabling batch listener mode in consumer.